# In Yocto how to append COMPATIBLE_MACHINE in my layer meta-test

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe, yocto-kirkstone

In Yocto kirkstone I'm adding support for new qemu added machine.conf(qemu-test.conf) file in my layer meta-test. How to append COMPATIBLE_MACHINE with my machine qemu-test for the  kernel recipe linux-yocto_5.10.bb in my layer with bbappend ?

```
COMPATIBLE_MACHINE = "^(qemuarm|qemuarmv5|qemuarm64|qemux86|qemuppc|qemuppc64|qemumips|qemumips64|qemux86-64|qemuriscv64|qemuriscv32)$"
```